# Large JSON not stored if stored when processed in a job

Tags: laravel, symfony

I got a strange problem. I am using use Symfony\Component\Process\Process to get the output of a docker-run.

I created this Job class:

```
public function handle()
    {
        $process = new Process([
            'docker',
            'run',
            'my/container:4.5.0',
            $this->url    
        ]);

        $process->setTimeout(3600);
        $process->setIdleTimeout(3600);
        $process->run();

        Result::create([
            'result' => json_decode(strstr($process->getOutput(), '{'))
        ]);
    }
```

If I dispatch this Job within a shell command, I don't get a 'result'.

If I run this directly from the Console command like this:

```
  $url   = $this->argument('url');
        $this->line("Starting test for $url");
//        $result = ProcessJob::dispatch($url);
        $process = new Process([
            'docker',
            'run',
            'my/container:4.5.0',         
            $url    
        ]);

        $process->setTimeout(3600);
        $process->run();
       
          Result::create([
            'result' => json_decode(strstr($process->getOutput(), '{')),
        ]);

        return 0;
```

I get an result.

Now it's getting even more complicated:

This works perfectly fine on my Homestead machine - but not on my virtual server I hosted on a datacenter.

What I did:

- I checked, if the docker command can run on that user (true, otherwise the console-command would fail
- I checked the Laravel-log (no entry)
- I checked the MySQL-log (no entry)

Comment: Some questions: The process is executed correctly? `docker ps -a` reports your container as exited successfully? `docker logs <your container id>` returns anything? Is there any difference between your dev env and your prod env (ex: developing on macos and executing on debian)?

Comment: You are not checking your if the process run was succesfull, your output is probably here: getErrorOutput(), refer to the symphony doc for using process, how you should use it. https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

Comment: Yep - that was my missing point. I found out that docker was unable to run as non-root user, because the docker-examples to do so included changes in `.bashrc`, which of course is not interpreted by php.